# Display similar words from Json List

Tags: php, json

im trying to display from a list of keywords of json file words that contain  words from a keyword searched, but the data inst displaying, cant figure out the problem.

Result to be displayed:

- Programmer PHP
- Programme Java
  ...

Here is the code:

Json:

```
{
   "list":[
      {
         "key":"Programmer PHP",
         "value":"Programmer PHP"
      },
      {
         "key":"Programmer JAVA",
         "value":"Programmer JAVA"
      },
      {
        "key":"Programmer C++",
         "value":"Programmer C++"
      }
   ]
}
```

PHP:

```
$q = "Programmer";
$url = 'what.json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$count = 0;
foreach($json['list'] as $i){

    echo "<li><a href=''>".strstr($i['value'],$q)."</a></li>";
    $count++;
    if($count >= 6){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How similar do the words have to be? And why are `Programmer PHP`
and `Programme Java` considered similar, and `Programmer C++` is not?

Comment: Who said "Programmer C++" is not? I putted the "..." just to not continue writing. Basically words that contains the keyword "Programmer" is considered similar.

Comment: It works for me, check that url is correct.

Comment: Well if you simply want to check if `$q` appears in your list, put an if test for it before echoing: `foreach($json['list'] as $i){
    if (strpos($i['value'], $q) !== false) {
        echo "<li><a href=''>".$i['value']."</a></li>";
        $count++;
        if($count >= 6){
            break;
        }
    }
}
` otherwise you'll get blank entries where it doesn't (up to a limit of 6)

Comment: Code seems right. Nothing is outputted ?How is the  `json_decode` result ? Try a `var_dump` on $json.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker is working great, only one last question, i notice that appears duplicate keywords from my query (Programmer), how could i make it not count these duplicate words?

Comment: Already resolved the issue, thanks anyway @MarkBaker